# Why does “propositional calculus” have the word “calculus” in it?

Tags: calculus, analysis, terminology, propositional-calculus, math-history

We define “calculus” like this:

“***Calculus is the mathematical study of continuous change.***”

But if that’s the case, then why is the study of (true or false) propositions and their relations called:

“*Propositional* ***calculus***”?

These are some example statements from both fields:

> This is something from calculus: $\int_{0}^{3} x^2 dx = 3$

> This is something from propositional calculus: $((A \rightarrow B)\land A) \rightarrow B$

What I know from a historical standpoint is that “calculus” was originally a word for “small pebble” and then evolved into a word for “calculation”. However, I also know that propositional calculus was developed somewhere in the 19th century, which is way after calculus was used for “calculation”.

Why are both of these using the term “calculus”? Is its meaning as “calculation” related?

Comment: "Why are both of these a 'calculus'? Is its meaning as 'calculation' related?" [Yes.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calculus)

Comment: Calculus is used a lot more broadly than the introductory course because of its historical usage.

Comment: See e.g. [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/c/)

Comment: There are lots of *calculus* in mathematics and in logic. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_(disambiguation)).

Comment: _“Calculus is the mathematical study of continuous change.”_ Wrong wording IMO, **analysis** would fit better.

Comment: See [Who first used the word "calculus"](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2901/who-first-used-the-word-calculus-and-what-did-it-describe). Thus, *propositional calculus* derives not from calculus=real analysis but from the older calculus=computation, i.e. formal operations based on rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Definition :

Douglas N. Clark "DICTIONARY of Analysis, Calculus, and Differential Equations" gives this Entry, with my highlighting and emphasis:

> **calculus** (1.) The study of properties of
> functions of one or several variables, using
> derivatives and integrals. Differential calcu-
> lus usually refers to the one variable study
> of the derivative and its applications and in-
> tegral calculus to the study of the Riemann
> integral of a function of one variable. **Classi-
>
> cally, it has been referred to as *"the"* calculus.**
> (2.) Any system of computations based upon
> some unifying idea, such as the **calculus** of
> residues or **calculus** of variations.

### Overview :

Etymologically , **"calculi" & "calculus"** come from **PEBBLE** which was used for measuring geographical distances and such.
[[ Currently, "calculate" is the most general term covering all mathematical computations and even more. ]]

With that came **"infinitesimal calculus"** , which is generally shortened to just "calculus" , the most common abd well known type.

- **"Propositional Calculus"** involves calculating truth values of Statements , hence it uses the word "Calculus".
- We have **"Predicate Calculus"** , where we calculate truth values with Statements involving various quantifiers & variables.
- **"Variational Calculus"** is concerned with calculating & optimizing functionals.
- **"Lambda Calculus"** is the mathematical theory of computation the calculations involve Expressions, variables, functions, and various abstractions including Turing Machines.
  In general, these terms are not shortened.

**All these are about calculations and computations, within various domains.**

### Summary:

When we have "W Calculus" or "X Calculus" or "Y Calculus" or "Z Calculus", we make calculations involving type W or type X or type Y or type Z. To avoid confusion, we do not shorten it.

When we have "infinitesimal calculus", we make calculations involving infinitesimal quantities, ratios, limits & real numbers. We shorten that to just "calculus" since it is the most common.

Comment: Also calculus of finite differences, and umbral calculus, but not renal calculus.

Comment: Yes , "covering all mathematical computations & even more" , here the "even more" was for cases like "renal calculus" , @bof , I know very little about the "umbral calculus" , thank you for sharing that !!

Comment: @Prem For future reference, punctuation like commas, periods, and colons come directly after the words which precede them, with no space.

Answer (score -2):

The proper term for the study of integrals, derivatives, etc, is "differential calculus".  It is incorrectly shortened to "calculus".  You can probably tell from words like "calculator" or "calculation" that "calculus" can refer to a lot more than methods of manipulating differentials.

Comment: This is not correct in modern English, where "calculus" (without any other adjective) refers to the study of functions, as introduced by Leibniz and Newton.  It roughly refers to examination of limits, continuity, differentiability, and integration.  This has also been historically referred to as "the calculus".  To say that it is *incorrect* to use the word "calculus" in this manner to is to fall for the etymological fallacy. As Prem points out in their answer, the word "calculus" also has deeper etymological roots; there are other uses of "calculus" which don't refer to "the calculus".

Comment: @XanderHenderson Excuse my rudeness, but to be blunt, if you think "that is the modern way to use a word, so it must be correct", then you shouldn't be correcting people on etymology.  Words change meaning for many different reasons, and not all of them informed or honest, and often it is to the detriment of language.

Comment: Generally, correct usage of words is defined by the way that people with the relevant knowledge use those words. The use of the bare word "calculus" to refer to that branch of mathematics seems to be common among people with the relevant knowledge, including in careful writing. On the face of it, that seems to make that usage correct. Maybe I'm wrong about all this, and that usage of the word "calculus" actually is incorrect as you say, but you really ought to give your reasons for saying so.

Comment: @DanielV (1) I did not correct you on etymology.  I noted that you committed the [etymologically fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy), i.e. you falsely asserted that because "calculus" originally meant one thing, it is somehow incorrect to assert that it no longer means precisely that thing, and therefore incorrect to use it in any other way.

Comment: (2) As an undergraduate, I studied anthropology, which included taking several courses in cultural linguistics.  One of the discussions which recurs in those classes is the distinction between prescriptivism and descriptivism.  You are clearly a prescriptivist, which puts you in a very small minority.  The word "calculus" refers to a narrow set of topics, and asserting that this is "wrong" is nothing more than shaking your fist at the clouds.  This simply isn't the way in which the word is used or understood in modern English.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'll make this my last response since this isn't an etymology forum.  Your first two clauses contradict each  other.  Reducing etymology to "prescriptivism and descriptivism" is absurd.  Both ignore the real reasons that the use of language changes.  And you are completely missing what I said, that the *transition* from "differential calculus" to "calculus" was erroneous, something evident to anyone who knows the meanings of the words.  And although I know you meant that I am an intellectual minority as a criticism, all I can say is "thank you for the compliment".

Comment: I have not made a single argument about the etymology of the word "calculus"---I have attacked the structure of your argument.  There is also a world of difference between the statements "...the transition from "differential calculus" to "calculus" **was** erroneous..." and what you wrote in your post:  "It **is** incorrectly shortened to "calculus".  The former is an opinionated discussion of etymology; the latter is prescriptivist grumbling.  Perhaps I am missing your point because you are failing to clearly make it...